# How to push to LAN repository

Tags: git, git-server

I have a git bare project setup on my laptop, from my desktop I cloned it, modified a couple of files and wanted to push it, but getting error:

```
remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename //MACBOOK/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Dev/project.git/./objects/incoming-xxxx/46/76325e2cdd34d7d3: Permission denied
```

I access to remote my repository with user and password.
how can I push changes to the repository?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: `origin  //MACBOOK/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Dev/project.git (fetch)`
`origin  //MACBOOK/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Dev/project.git (push)`

Answer (score 1):

Few reasons

## SSH keys

In your case, doesn't seem like the problem since you have local repo under your account

## Shared repository configuration

```
# try to set this flag to true
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

> **`core.sharedRepository`**
>
> When group (or true), the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable).
>
> When all (or world or everybody), the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable.
>
> **False by default.**

Comment: I set it to true, no luck

Comment: Ok, what is the output of `git fetch --all`

Comment: `git --fetch --all
Unknown option: --fetch
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]`

Comment: Sorry typo: `git fetch --all`

Comment: `git fetch --all
Fetching origin`

Comment: And still, get an error you push? do you have write permissions to the desired folder?

Comment: Thank you @CodeWizard for your help, I restarted everything, cloned repository with `git clone git+ssh:// ` and now able to push! I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Sure glad to help. Good luck